# updating multi level mongoose arrays based on specific value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema that has an array which contains items and another array

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CompanySchema = new Schema({

  dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },

  ownerId: { type: String },

  ceo: { type: String },

  shareHolders: [{
    userId: { type: String },
    shares: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    role: { type: String },
    agreements: [{
      agreementID: { type: String },
    }]
  }],

  team: [{
      userId:     { type: String },
      position:   { type: String }

  }],



});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Company', CompanySchema);
```

I am trying to first check if there is an item inside of the shareholders array that contains a specific value for the userID, then I need to update the shareholder item and push a new agreementID into the agreement array. I spent quite a few hours googling and stack exchanging but cannot seem to achieve this.

this is what I have so far FYI this seems to always create a new shareholder never update an existing one.

to update the shareholder I am trying this

```
  Company.update({
      "_id": req.companyID,
      "shareHolders.userId": req.userID
    }, {
      $push: {
        "shareHolders.$.agreements.agreementID": req.agreementID
      }
    }, {
      $set: {
        "shareHolders.$.shares": ++req.shares
      }
    },
    function(err) {

      if (err) {
        callback(err, err);
      } else {
        callback(null, 'success');
      }
    })
```

to find if the shareholder exists this always results in shareholder does not exist? and creates a new shareholder

```
  function checkShareHolder() {
    console.log('checkShareHolder');
    var date = moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    var data = {
      companyID: agreement.applicant.applicantCompanyID,
      userID: agreement.coSigner.coSignerID
    }

    company_worker.getCompanyByID(agreement.applicant.applicantCompanyID, function(err, result) {

      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
      } else {

        company = result;
        console.log('checkShareHolder');
        process.nextTick(function() {
          looper()
        });

      }

    })


    function looper() {

      var updateShareholder = 'false';
      var addShareHolder = 'false';
      console.log('looper');
      console.log(company.shareHolders);


      if (company.shareHolders.length > 0) {

        async.forEach(company.shareHolders, function(item, callback) {

          console.log(item);
          if (item.userID == agreement.coSigner.coSignerID) {
            console.log('updateShareholder = true'),
              updateShareholder = 'true',
              callback()

          } else(
            console.log('addShareHolder = true'),
            addShareHolder = 'true',
            callback()

          )

        }, function(err) {

          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }

          if (addShareHolder == 'true') {
            console.log('looper addShareHolder');
            process.nextTick(function() {
              addShareholder()
            });
          } else if (updateShareholder == 'true') {
            console.log('looper updateShareholder');
            process.nextTick(function() {
              updateShareholder()
            });
          }

        });
      } else {

        console.log('looper addShareHolder as nothing found');
        process.nextTick(function() {
          addShareholder()
        });

      }


    }


  };
```

Comment: FYI, there's an extra 's' in `agreements.agreementsID` in $push.

Comment: wow thanks for pointing that out amazing! ill retest the code see if it works lol

Comment: so now the issue is that instead of updating the existing shareholder it creates a new shareholder.

Comment: That's what $push does. "The $push operator appends a specified value to an array."

Comment: so do i maybe use set instead to update the existing shareholder and push a new item to his agreements array

Comment: It looks like you should be using `{
      $push: {
        "shareHolders.$.agreements":{agreementID: req.agreementID}
      }
    }` based on schema OR change your schema to  `agreements: [{ type: String }]` and use `{
      $push: {
        "shareHolders.$.agreements": req.agreementID
      }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like you should be using { $push: { "shareHolders.$.agreements":{agreementID: req.agreementID} } } based on schema OR change your schema to agreements: [{ type: String }] and use { $push: { "shareHolders.$.agreements": req.agreementID } } – Veeram

works perfect thank you everyone for your help